# How to send a message to a Router pre-connection

Tags: c++, c, network-programming

I’m working on a university project where we’re basically trying to recreate the Reaver WPS attack. Originally the plan was to reimplement it in Python or Ruby but as we don’t have a good starting point right now, we are going to start with C/C++.

The problem is, we don’t actually know where to start. Our first ideas were to use Wireshark to try and sniff some packets and see what’s actually happening.

I think we know that we’re going to be working with raw sockets and I’m going to be sending a message to a router to simulate the PIN. Is this different than sending a message to another computer, or should I be sending this to my default gateway, and otherwise what port should i be asking on?

Also any suggestions for libraries that we could use to code this up in Ruby or Python would be greatly appreciated. Especially libraries that would be related to connecting and managing wireless networks and working with raw sockets.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual reaver-wps source code?

Comment: @KillianDS We actually have but, it's a huge project with dozens of files. We don't really know where to start looking, but we will do that at some point.

Comment: @MartinJames These are not appropriate questions and have nothing to do with the question at hand.

Comment: OK. I will try to be clearer.  Are you soliciting help with illegal and/or immoral activites?

Comment: @MartinJames No, this is for a project. I don't know what I can say to  convince you otherwise. We're literally trying to make something that has already been release and is part of a Backtrack distribution. If we wanted to do something illegal and immoral we have access to better tools already.

Comment: Unfortunately, asking for help with hacker tools is likely to result in suspicion and lack of cooperation.  I'm sure you understand that.

Comment: @MartinJames I understand, but I still feel that my original question had nothing to do with illegal activity. I wasn't saying anything like, "hey I've exploited X and I need to help to further exploit X." I'm asking for a legitimate networking question. I'm just a student hoping to get some advice from the awesome Stack community.

Comment: It's a hacker tool.  You may indeed have some legitimate use for it, but the fact is that hacker tools don't have many legitimate uses.  I don't know that you're a hacker, just that you might be.

Comment: You are trying to recreate the attack without understanding how it works? Shouldn't that be your step #1?

Comment: If this is a university project you should have a prof or someone who should be able to help you and give you directions. So as this question is so basic I can not imagine that you were told to "hack a router" but without any help or literature?

Comment: @blueshift we have a basic understanding of the attack, but we're just trying to find out how to send a message to a router. We know how to use sockets, but how do you talk to a router?

Comment: @Vash This is a free form project, we got to pitch the idea to our professor and she would decide if we could continue.

Comment: A router is just a regular IP host.   You communicate with it just like any other IP host.   If you're trying to assemble a packet which traverses the router, the simplest thing to do is add an appropriate routing entry to your routing table.

Comment: @Uri If you haven't already take a look at our [blog](http://www.tacnetsol.com/news/2011/12/28/cracking-wifi-protected-setup-with-reaver.html) and [Stefan's whitepaper](http://sviehb.files.wordpress.com/2011/12/viehboeck_wps.pdf).  The python packet library [scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/) would be a great place to start.  Feel free to contact us on twitter  [tacnetsol](http://twitter.com/tacnetsol) [devttys0](http://twitter.com/devttys0) [hacintosh](http://twitter.com/hacintosh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out reaver here: [link](http://code.google.com/p/reaver-wps/source/checkout)

The code is very well documented.
If you take a look at "send.c" in the source, it should have the type of code you are looking for.